# Rails include model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pusher

is there a way to load model association without eager loading? im trying to push an object to the browser with model associations included.

`push_to_user` pushes the `@todo` object to the browser. a javascript listener will read the data and print it out.

The issue im having is that `@todo` doesn't include its model association (e.g. "categories"). how can i include that?

```
@todo = Todo.find(1)
puts @todo.item.categories  # eager load categories. works

# push object to pusher
Pusher.push_to_user(@todo, user)

# custom pusher method
def self.push_to_user(todo, user)
    Pusher['private-1'].trigger('activity', {:todo => todo, :user => user})
end

# Browser
console.log(todo) # categories are missing
```

thanks
pete

Answer (score 0):

I think the better is add a new key with this categories :

```
def self.push_to_user(todo, user)
    Pusher['private-1'].trigger('activity', {:todo => todo, :categories => todo.categories, :user => user})
end
```

Comment: hm yeah that would work. but is there another solution?
i kinda want to keep everything related to @todo in this one object, if possible

Comment: I think you need generate a `#serializable_hash` of your todo with `:include => :categories`. I add another answer with this proposition.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a `#serializable_hash` method on your todo with an `:include => categories`

```
def self.push_to_user(todo, user)
    Pusher['private-1'].trigger('activity', {:todo => todo.serializable_hash(:include => :categories), :user => user})
end
```

I don't test this solution but can works.